# Why are my attempts to send keys to element failed?

Tags: python

I tried this code:

```
email = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "text-color-text font-sans text-md outline-0 bg-color-transparent grow")
email.send_keys("hiiiiiii")
```

And this is the error message:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Then I tried:

```
email = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "text-color-text font-sans text-md outline-0 bg-color-transparent grow")[0]
email.send_keys("hiiiiiii")
```

And this is the error message:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It means that `driver.find_elements` returns an empty list. Not much more to say.

Comment: We need a [MCVE]. I can't even figure out what packages you're using, what the inputs are, what you expect it to do, etc. trincot is describing the problem, so maybe you've just got a bad selector, but we can't say a single thing more than that without actual information.

Comment: If you're expecting to find a single element, use `find_element()`, not `find_elements()`.

Comment: Can you show us an html sample of the element you expected to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first try calls `find_elements`, which returns a list and therefore you cannot call `send_keys` on it. Your second element attempts to get the first element via `[0]`, which is, by the way, almost logically equivalent to calling `find_element` (but `find_elements` will not raise an exception upon the element not being found). Here you already attempt to get a single element, but the list was empty in the first place.

So, you will need to look into your selector. Maybe your elements do not have all the classes. Maybe some elements have some classes from your classes, some other elements have some other classes. If so, you could use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` instead, with the actual selector being `.classname1, .classname2, .classname3` and of course, you will need to use your own class names here.